# How to pass an intent to other activity, and execute the intent passed to that other activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

As the question says, how can i do that, i saw some reference through google before but I can't find it now, when i really needed it! please help!

Comment: You cannot 'execute' an Intent. It is just a message. If you want to start another activity using an Intent use the setComponent method and to pass custom data use the putExtra methods in the Intent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the `PendingIntent` class? You can create it using the `PendingIntent.getActivity()` method, send it to other activity and run it using `PendingIntent.send()` method.